# How to get sender ID in page conversations/messages{message}? Facebook Graph API 8.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messages

I'm accessing page conversations and their messages using this reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/conversation

My steps are:

1. v8.0/{page_id}?fields=conversations

This returns a list of conversation IDs i.e t_1000000000, t_200000000...

2. v8.0/t_1000000000?fields=messages{message}

This returns all messages in the conversation, however sender ID is not available - I can't tell if the page sent it or the user sent it.

What's the best way to get the sender ID for each message?

I can get sender ID from:

v8.0/t_1000000000?fields=senders, but how do I use this to filter messages?

Thank you

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion

Answer (score 0):

```
t_10217618258955338?fields=messages{message,from,id}
```

[image]

Comment: A good answer will include some instructions in plain English.

Comment: Please share the request in plain text for other users